# how to use an uploaded image in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to upload an image and then edit it but I do not know how to keep the uploaded image in different parts 
now I am using global variable but I need another way because if different user work with my app at the same time it can not distinguish the images
   #views.py

```
def Edit(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=picform(request.POST , request.FILES)
        if (form.is_valid()) :
            global anghezi
            anghezi=pic.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            global epic
            epic=anghezi.pic
            anghezi.save
        contex={"item":anghezi}
        return render(request,'edit.html',contex)
def show(request):
    global epic
    im = Image.open(epic.url[1:])
    return render(request,'show.html',{"im":epic})
def share(request):
    global anghezi
    anghezi.shar=True
    anghezi.save()
    p=pic.objects.filter(shar=True).order_by("uploaded_at")
    return render(request,'share.html',{'p':p})
```

Comment: @wpercy thanks for your remark

Comment: `how to keep the uploaded image in different parts` in different parts of *what*? Please describe the active parties of *upload* and *edit*, respectively.